# Error 429: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute per user'

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, knex.js, google-cloud-run

We migrated a service from GCP App Engine to Cloud Run. This service is connected to Cloud SQL.
[image]

and its parameters are:

- max requests per container: 1
- min instances: 0
- max instances: 200

After receiving spikes, we have experienced this error multiple times:

```
Cloud SQL connection failed. Please see https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-overview for additional details: googleapi: Error 429: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Queries' and limit 'Queries per minute per user' of service 'sqladmin.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:370240628xxx'., rateLimitExceeded
```

The quota *Queries per minute per user* in *Cloud SQL Admin API* is set to 180. So this is obviously the point of failure.

I found out that the quota limit is hit due to the way how Cloud Run is connected to the Cloud SQL instance. As [this link](https://www.keypup.io/blog/cloud-run-and-cloud-sql-avoid-hitting-cloud-sql-admin-connection-quota) says:

> The native connection leverages the Cloud SQL Auth proxy which in turns makes requests to the Cloud SQL Admin API. This API - like all GCP APIs - has throttling quotas which will prevent containers from starting once reached.

The tutorial on the same website suggests using VPC connector instead of the normal Cloud SQL connection. But I've seen Google's [docs](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_user) and other stackoverflow posts suggesting adding [*quotaUser*](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/system-parameters#definitions) parameter somehow.

What would be the optimal solution? I would normally go for the VPC but since that is a paid service, I try to avoid that obviously. Since I already pay for Cloud Run and Cloud SQL, I expect those two to be connected without issues and additional costs.

Thank you for all your tips and help!

Comment: Can you open a ticket to the support and ask them if it's a hard limit or  soft limit? It could solve your issue.

Comment: I know that it is a limit I can change. But that's not scalable at all. You can find and edit this limit in `APIs & services` --> `Cloud SQL Admin API`

Comment: As Arnaud (the author) mentioned in the link where I took the quote from, it probably uses Cloud SQL Auth proxy. Weird. He solves that by using VPC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **Short explanation:**

We solved the issue by using the VPC serverless connector (VPC network -> Serverless VPC access) that allows us to create an internal network.

The quota "Queries per minute per user" is for Cloud SQL Admin API. Since we use an internal network now, we don't hit this API and its limits.

### **Steps:**

1. **Register a new VPC serverless connector.** Can be found in VPC network -> Serverless VPC access. We chose the "default" network, set the IP address range to "10.8.0.0/28" and "e2-micro" as an instance type. Regarding the region, we specified "europe-west1" since our Cloud Run services are based there. As [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access) says, the VPC's region must match your services' region to work.
2. You must enable "Private IP" for your SQL. It can be found in SQL -> Connections. We chose the "default" network and chose Google to generate the address for us. It took a few seconds for Google to finish this process.
3. Then, to set these settings, you have to press the "SAVE" button, **BUT** be careful as the process that follows takes a few minutes to complete (7min in our case)
4. We went to SQL -> Overview and copied the newly generated "Private IP address".
5. Then, we used this address as an environment variable in our Cloud Run as SQL_HOST. Before, the SQL_HOST variable was "Connection name" instead, which had this form "project-name:europe-west3:database-name". So this was replaced with the "Private IP".

It worked, although we think Google should do this by default. Cloud Run is supposed to be a service that can be scaled to high numbers, but you quickly find out that there are issues resulting from the increasing traffic.

### **UPDATE:**

We ended up creating a new VPC network just for the connection from Cloud Run services to the database. So instead of "default", we assigned our database and the serverless VPC connector to this newly created network. This way we can easily modify how many IP addresses we want to allow without interfering with other machines in the network.

Answer (score 3):

> max requests per container: 1
> min instances: 0
> max instances: 200

Wow, that's a strange setup.

The above means you have concureny=1. And you have for each request a brand new container firing up. All your request have slow starts.

You should increase `max requests per container` up to a threshold that your container based on the process that it runs can keep up, eg: 80 request/container for a simple webservice with 512MB sounds good. Experiment with this.

Increasing concurrency from 1 to 80, it means 1 single database connection can be reused, and you are not hitting the other limits.

ps. I am not aware of any method that you can specify `quotaUser` for the SQL connection, which is a `unix socket` type connection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although I think your answer is not relevant to this question. It is more of a general suggestion. There is a reason why we have this setup and I would expect this to work if there is this option.

Comment: It does not have 512MB; I've never said that. The memory allocation is 2048Mi.

Comment: Let us know the reason of your setup, it would really come handful to provide further guidance. Also you could add to your post, this reason to understand why it's a hard limit. What is the execution time of your request? Is there a requirement to have low latency or can accommodate some latency. Why I am asking? You could setup a Cloud Run service with high concurrency just for the DB layer, and all the existing services could use that Cloud Run service to access the Database like `Cloud Run(frontend) -> Cloud Run (db layer) -> SQL.`

Comment: We run Puppeteer as a container, and to avoid various crashes and errors, we decided to run one browser per instance all the time. There are thousands of requests per day, so it makes sense to have a number of instances much higher. Even if I set the concurrency to a higher number, we will experience the same issue if our services grow even more, which is expected. I went for VPC for now and created a private network. Now the connections are not established via public IP and API but internally. I think this might solve the issue but not sure yet. We will test it tomorrow.

Comment: If you know about a different approach or have any other recommendations, I would be thankful for those.

Comment: What's your code to lanch the page inside puppeteer? Have you explored firing up one browser instance, and each request into it's own pagetab?

Comment: We launch the browser and immediately after that we navigate to the page, then the browser is closed. We were discussing the exact same strategy as you proposed. Still need some discussion but we may implement it in the near future. Thanks a lot for your time and help! :) I will upvote your answer since it can lead to good practices and is a good general recommendation.

Comment: Currently, it seems like the VPC network I added yesterday solves the issue since it does not hit the API quota. I will know for sure today evening and then will answer my own question with the solution.

Comment: VPC Connector is not serverless. VPC connector is a masked VM proxy. It's always ON, and has it's own scaling settings. Also please be informed that scaling settings the defaults, are 2 (min) and 10 (max). The connector scales out to the maximum specified if traffic usage requires it, but the connector does not scale back in when traffic decreases. So you are paying the instance. You are able to choose the instance type yourself, if the default `e2-micro` is not working out for you. If you want to be truly serverless, than do I suggested Cloud Run (frontend) -> Cloud Run (API-DB access) -> DB

Comment: That is our only option if we are running with the concurrency = 1. There is no other option. I don't really know what you mean by "frontend" since what we are talking about is only a backend service, there is no frontend.

Comment: By frontend I mean a service that doesn't have the SQL connection, so it scales up with no problem. And the middle-layer service could have concurrency as that would have the SQL connection. It means separate the DB read/write layer into it's own Cloud Run service. And call it from other Cloud Run service.

Comment: So you meant "client", not "frontend". It is not a bad idea but it is not scalable as well. In the case of multiple databases, I would need to have multiple Cloud Run SQL connectors. This would increase complexity. And also, I would need to pay for these connector services as well. I don't think it would be even cheaper than VPC in this case.

Comment: You won't need VPC this way, and the connector-service should be fairly cheap, as can be set for high concurrency, so literally, you will pay 1-2 instances.

Comment: @MichalMoravik Can you please let us know if using VPC solved your issue? If yes can you please post it as an answer for visibility?